# Trouble getting globalShortcut to register commands to index.js using send function in node/electron javascript app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

for some reason my code is compiling with no error, however, my message "Helloworld" is not displaying properly in the console. however my test message is being displayed when i press the bound key combinations. below is my set of code, index.js and main.js

This is written for node/electron.
My main.js file:

> ```
>    //main.js
>
>    //requirements
>    const electron = require('electron');
>    const app = require('electron').app;
>    const BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
>    const remote = require('electron').remote;
>    const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;
>    const globalShortcut = require('electron').globalShortcut;
>
>    var mainWindow = null;
>
>    //create app, instantiate window
>    app.on('ready', function() {
>        mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
>            frame: false,
>            height: 700,
>            resizable: false,
>            width: 368
>        });
>
>        mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html`);
>
>        //this is the icp bind
>        globalShortcut.register('ctrl+shift+1', function(){
>            console.log("test")
>            mainWindow.webContents.send("testBindicp" ,"HelloWorld");
>        });
>
>        //this is the remote bind
>        globalShortcut.register('ctrl+shift+2', function(){
>            console.log("test")
>            mainWindow.webContents.send("testBindicp" ,"HelloWorld");
>        });
>    });
>
>    //close the app
>    ipc.on('close-main-window', function () {
>        app.quit();
>    });
> ```

below is my entire index.js:

> ```
>    //index.js
>    const globalShortcut = require('electron').globalShortcut;
>    const remote = require('electron').remote;
>    const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
>
>    //testing remote render from remote bind
>    remote.require('./main.js');
>    remote.on('testBindRemote', function(event){
>        console.log(event + " - test - from remote index.js");
>    });
>
>    //testing icpRenderer from icp bind
>    ipc.on('testBindicp', function (event) {
>        console.log(event + " - test - from icpRenderer on index.js")
>    });
>
>   //close the app
>    var closeEl = document.querySelector('.close');
>    closeEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
>        ipc.send('close-main-window');
>    });
> ```

the problem i'm having is when i press the keyboard binds, only the console logs from the main.js file are being send to the console. the close command is still working within the rendered window, but any other commands in the index.js window are not being bound to the proper main.js elements.

if i am doing something wrong, please let me know the proper way to implement these methodologies, as the remote and icp structures seem to be confusing to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have another argument passed into the listening process `ipc.on`  of index.js file, make it something like this:

```
ipc.on(<channel name>, function (event, arg) {
       console.log(arg + " - test - from icpRenderer on index.js");
   });
```

for more info, visit [webContents API docs](https://xwartz.gitbooks.io/electron-gitbook/content/en/api/web-contents.html)